# why my php file can't read the style sheet, even the html do for the same style

Tags: php, html, css

When I work with PHP, sometimes I can't see the changes that I make in CSS file, and when I tried to convert the '.php' to '.html', the page read the changes normally.
Can anyone help!

Comment: In order to help you, we're going to need to see the contents of your file and we're going to need a better explanation of the problem. Please see "How do I ask a good question?" here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In the browsers development tools, you can tell it not to cache files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try clear cache ?
You can also try load page with ctrl+f5 
Or load your web page with private windows(ctrl+shift+n in chrome)

Comment: yeah it's working, thanks bro